# ERR PARSE SQL syntax error

Tags: database-design, syntax, syntax-error

I am getting this error:

> ERR PARSE ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check manual that corresponds to your mariadb server version for the right syntax to use near 'continue)

In my server I have this:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(connString);
console.log("Query: " + sql);
connection.query(sql, [req.body.negocio, req.body.status, req.body.to_do, req.body.work_completed, req.body.comment, req.body.continue], function (err, rows, fields) {
    connection.end();
```

In my app.js I have this:

```
$scope.comment = function () {
    var comment = {
        negocio: bus.name,
        status: $scope.status,
        to_do: $scope.to_do,
        work_completed: $scope.work_completed,
        comment: $scope.comentario,
        continue: $scope.continue
    }
```

The logfile shows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE app.js:315 Errornull
>   -1 [object Object]

Can someone explain me the error?

Comment: What is the content of your `sql` variable? Can you check your log for the output of your console.log message in the above code?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
app.js:315 Errornull -1 [object Object]

Comment: I added the log message from your comment to the question. Editing your question with clarifications like this is something you should do. The question should make sense without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

## ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is often caused by client-side problems, not your code

I think this is one of those confusing times when you are programming, and a problem occurs on your machine that has little to do with your actual code.

Try to validate this by viewing this page on another computer. If that’s not available, try from a different browser or in your browser’s incognito mode.

If you can’t replicate this on another computer, then try to replicate it on a different browser on your own computer.

#### Fixing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE that occurs only in one browser

If the problem occurs in only one browser, then delete the “personal” info on that browser. It’s probably not going to be necessary to remove your saved bookmarks or passwords; start by deleting cache.

#### Fixing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE that occurs on all browsers of one computer

If you are seeing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on several browser of one computer, the problem is probably is some corrupted cached network data your computer uses.

If you have made changes to your computer’s networking configuration, perhaps by adding items to your hosts file, try rolling these back to the original versions.

#### Windows

On windows, you can go to the command line and run `ifconfig/renew`, and then restart your computer.

On Mac, the method for clearing the DNS cache varies by OS version, [check here](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-flush-dns-in-mac-os-x/).

If your machine still won’t behave, but the problem is isolated to your machine (or to one browser) you might try asking this problem on Stack SuperUser.